# Styling checkbox sibling element when checkbox is checked

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

JSX :

```
<input 
type="checkbox" 
defaultChecked={myfilter.includes("Banana")}
/>
<span 
    onClick={onClickHandler}
    className="banana">Banana
</span>
```

Without React :

```
`<input 
    type="checkbox" 
/>
<span 
    className="banana">Banana
</span>`
```

The goal is to select and style the span element when the input element status is checked.
The reason why I need to do this way is that the checkbox element is hidden by default.
I tried this, but did not worked :

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + :after{
  background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to change the span element background or its after pseudo element's background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chamhe `:after` to `span`\

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span{
 background: yellow;
}
```